# How do I check whether both parallel AsyncTask threads are finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm calling two AsyncTasks in parallel via this snippet in `onCreate`:

```html
        if ((DictMode.equals("TATOEBA")) || (DictMode.equals("SENTENCE"))) {

            dictAsyncTask = new DictAsyncTask(DictionaryLookUp.this, "Tatoeba");
//            dictAsyncTask.execute();
            dictAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }

        if ((DictMode.equals("JUKUU")) || (DictMode.equals("SENTENCE"))) {

            dictAsyncTask = new DictAsyncTask(DictionaryLookUp.this, "Jukuu");
//            dictAsyncTask.execute();
            dictAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
```

during `onPostExecute` I check whether any data gets retrieved and return from the `startActivityForResult` call via `finish`:

```html
            if (alldictStuff.size() == 0) {

               ...

               Toast.makeText(DictionaryLookUp.this,"NOTHING FOUND ...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               if ((DictMode.equals("TATOEBA")) || (DictMode.equals("JUKUU")) || (DictMode.equals("SENTENCE"))) {

                    Intent intentCard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CardView.class);

                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

                    finish();
                }
```

but that's obviously flawed since I'm not checking whether both threads return no results, so what's the best way to check whether both threads are finished and returned nothing ? Do I have to use my own variables to track it or is there something neat/built-in I can utilize ?

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly how you want to manage your business logic. 
From your onPostExecute() either send intent or send broadcast message to main thread or maintain async task status list and mark finished for each task from onPostExecute().